# Proper way to run a Mathematica script (-script vs -run vs MathematicaScript vs <)?

Tags: scripting, command-line

Suppose I have a Mathematica script called `test.m`. There at least 4 ways to run this from the terminal:

```
math -script test.m

math -run < test.m

math < test.m

MathematicaScript test.m

math -noprompt -run "<<test.m"
```

What are the differences between these? What is the recommended way to run a Mathematica script (that is, I would like to get a behavior similar to the one you get with a python script by running `python file.py`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure on which operating system you are and whether this makes a difference, but your 4 choice don't do the same.

```
math -run file.m
```

---

#### edit:

When you change this command to `math -run < file.m` then it does the same as the next (wrong) alternative.

---

Doesn't do anything with the content of `file.m` at all, because the `-run` option expects a *command* like `math -run Print[2]`. Additionally, the command is not ran in *batch mode* like you would expect it from a script. Instead, an interactive command-line *Mathematica* session is opened. This is the same (although the session is quit instantly) for

```
math < file.m
```

where the content of `file.m` *is* executed, but `file.m` is not considered to be a script. You can easily see this when you create a script file with *she-bang* like

```
#!/usr/local/bin/MathematicaScript -script

Print["Hello"]
```

the the output of `math < file.m` looks pretty awesome:

```
Mathematica 10.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2014 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= 
                                #1!
Out[1]= -script + -------------------------------
                  bin local MathematicaScript usr

In[2]:= In[2]:= Hello

In[3]:=
```

Your last alternative seems to miss the `-script` option which is (as stupid as this may sound) required, even for the `MathematicaScript` command. Therefore, I need to run

```
WolframScript -script file.m
```

or I get an error

> error: Need to provide the -script option. Usage: -script

which is pretty lame.

If I had to give a suggestion, I would tell you to always include the *she-bang* in your file and make the file executable with `chmod +x`. Then you can simply call

```
patrick@lenerd:~/tmp$ ./file.m 
    Hello
    patrick@lenerd:~/tmp$
```

Comment: I had forgotten a `<` in my second option (the one with `-run`). Taking into account your answer, I added a 5th option also using `-run`. Please see the edits in my question.

Comment: With the additional redirect (`<`) you get the same output as in `math < file.m`, because the she-bang is not valid Mathematica syntax (but usually required).

Comment: I am not sure whether this answer is just confusing or wrong (for V12.3) but when I run `math -run file.m` it starts an interactive mathematica session and does nothing with the file. (So it does what you describe for `math -run < file.m`.)

Answer (score 3):

From my experience and under **linux**:

> For MMA v10, I use:

```
MathematicaScript -script script_file
```

> For MMA v11, I use:

```
wolframscript -f script_file
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of a more condensed and current reply (Mathematica 11) I write my answer.

I think you should make use of the script option which is built to be used in the command line. For that, you have to have a file (named `file`) that would look like this:

```
#!/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.3/Executables/wolframscript -script (*Default installation place for Mathematica 11*)
(* Your Code *)
Print["Hello World"];
```

`file` doesnt have to be a `.m`. Assuming you are in Linux it can just be named `file` and given executable privileges by running the command `chmod +x file`.

You run your mathematica script in the command line with

```
./file
```

It can take commandline arguments as well as shown [here](https://wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/mathematica-shell-scripts/create-mathematica-script-from-your-code.html). Note: if your command arguments are not all numbers don't use the `ToExpression` part in `vars`. By default the rest of the `var` definition will return your arguments into a list of strings, and you can convert the desired argument to an expression as needed in your code.

Hope it helped. When I was trying to create my own script I would have liked a direct short answer like this.