# No output from Plot3D when run from a script

Tags: plotting

Running Mathematica 10 on Ubuntu 14.04.  When I run the following in the notebook it shows a plot.  When I run the same code from a script (`math < plot3d.test.m`) there is no graphical output.  The command line shows

```
Out[2]= -Graphics3D-
```

Code

```
fxy = -(Cos[x]^2 + Cos[y]^2)^2;
Plot3D[fxy, {x, -90, 90}, {y, -90, 90}]
```

I'm using an evaluation version.  Is this perhaps a limitation of the evaluation version?

Thanks.

Comment: No, it is not a limitation. In script mode (which you should invoke using `-script` option, [see here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61732/187)) there is no front end, which is required if you want graphical output. In commandline-mode you can use [JavaGraphics](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12487) to display your plot, but when you run it as script, the window is closed immediately.

Comment: When I run with `math -script somefile.m` I don't get any output.  The `math -script` option is useless when you need to see output.  The link you've included is vague.  What is the right way to run a Mathematica script when you need to see output?

Comment: If the JavaGraphics window closes immediately when run from a script it's useless.  Is the Notebook the only way to get graphics?

Comment: Let me make it more clear: There are different forms of *output*. When you want to print something to the console, then a terminal session of *Mathematica*, a redirect of a file into `math` or the `-script` mode will work. If you need to show a **graphics**, then this will not work, because you need a front end for this. When you run something as a script, then there is usually no need to *display* a graphics, because you want to automate some work or/and run several file in batch-mode. Can you please add more information about what you try to achieve?